# @Transactional in super classes not weaved when using load time weaving

Tags: java, spring, aspectj, load-time-weaving, compile-time-weaving

The project I am working on has a similar structure for the `DAOs` to the one bellow:

```
/** 
* Base DAO class
*/
@Transactional    
public class JPABase {

  @PersistenceContext
  private EntityManager entityManager;

  public void persist(Object entity) {
    entityManager.persist(entity);
  }
 //some more methods in here
}
```

and

```
/** 
* Generic DAO class implementation
*/
@Transactional 
public abstract class GenericDao extends JpaBase {
   //some methods in here
}
```

and

```
/** 
* Specialized DAO class
*/
@Repository
@Transactional
public class PersonDao extends GenericDao {
  //some methods in here
}
```

Until now, the project used compile time weaving, but the configuration has changed to use `<context:load-time-weaver/>` with `-javaagent:/opt/tomcat7-1/lib/spring-instrument.jar`.

Since this change has been applied, the `JpaBase`'s and `GenericDao`'s `@Transactional` annotations are not weaved anymore. Each time a service class calls the `persist` method on a `PersonDao` object, no transaction is started.

Noteworthy:

- this used to work in the past, when using compile time weaving.
- all the methods that are defined in the `PersonDao` are weaved correctly, but the ones inherited (e.g. `persist(Object entity)`) are NOT weaved.

Compile time weaving and load time weaving are supposed to do the same thing, just at different moments in time. Why has the weaving behaviour changed?

Comment: IIRC you need to specify packages for LTW, maybe you're missing one?

Comment: The whole project is included in the `within` attribute of the `<include>` element, in the `aop.xml` file.

Comment: Have you tried the tips and tricks from http://blog.timmattison.com/archives/2012/04/19/tips-for-debugging-springs-transactional-annotation/ ?

Comment: First, @Transactional only should be in JPABase subclass. Secontly, try to put spring-instrument-tomcat.jar inside /lib path on your Apache Tomcat directory and config your context.xml on /conf with the class loader to weaver (org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader)

Comment: We finally switched to compile time weaving. Everything is working fine now :)

Comment: Did you enable load-time weaving for AspectJ? Reading the docs, it seems like you either need to have a `META-INF/aop.xml` file present _on the classpath_ (in the war, instead of the jar?) or otherwise activate it via the code.  

See the [Spring docs for enabling load-time weaving](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/EnableLoadTimeWeaving.html) for more info.

Comment: @anca-n Could you post your solution as answer?

Comment: @ksokol my understanding is, that they went back to compile time weaving instead of load time (so no solution)...

Comment: Indeed we went back to compile time weaving and everything works fine now.

Comment: Maybe scanning of the JARs for @Servlet and other web annotatios loads the class without weaving. Try disabling the scan for your library. Also check http://tomcat.apache.org/tomcat-7.0-doc/config/loader.html#Standard_Implementation

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat default `classlLoader` is `WebappClassLoader`, but you need `TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader.

**There are two solutions**:

> 1. Modify WebappLoader.class

Change WebappLoader.java

```
private String loaderClass =  "org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader";
```

Replace：

```
private String loaderClass = "org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader";
```

Compile it and replaced the class file(catalina.jar), then it works.

Here is required dependency jars: `catalina.jar`,`tomcat-coyote.jar`,`tomcat-util.jar(/bin)`,`tomcat-juli.jar`

> 2. Modify context.xml:

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<Context>  
    <Loader loaderClass="org.springframework.instrument.classloading.tomcat.TomcatInstrumentableClassLoader"/>  
</Context>`

Answer (score -1):

You probably missing the public constructor chaining inside these classes, @Transactional will work only if classes are having public constructors and public methods.

Comment: the visibility of constructors doesn't matter. And the public methods only apply to proxy based AOP not when using Weaving.